# iOS - GPUImage - How can I return a small subimage inside GPUImageHarrisCornerDetectionFilter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gpuimage

I am using `@BradLarson`'s [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) (with much success), and I am trying to extend the `GPUImageHarrisCornerDetectionFilter` so that it will not only return the locations of the detected corners, but also a subimage of X pixels squared (say 10 px as an example) surrounding the location of each detected corner.

My question is about regarding the best way to go about this. I've tried a few, but am having some issues with performance, so I'm humbling asking for any users of GPUImage who might have some experience with this to lend me some thoughts.

What I've tried:
Inside `GPUImageHarrisCornerDetectionFilter.m`, I have extended the method:

```
-(void)extractCornerLocationsFromImageAtFrameTime:(CMTime)frameTime
```

to:

```
-(void)extractCornerLocationsFromImageAtFrameTime:(CMTime)frameTime
                             withIntermediateImage:(UIImage *)intermediateImage
```

which I have returning the a UIImage of the actual camera feed for every frame. Then for each detected corner, I'm cropping the image to X pixels squared surrounding the corner. Performance for this is flat out horrible on my iPhone 5, so I'm looking for advice on how to achieve the same result another way.

Does anyone have experience with this??? What might be the best route to return a cropped subimage (from the camera feed, or another filter in the chain) for each corner detected in the Harris corner detection? I hope my question make sense.

Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: How do you actually get the corner coordinates from the still image? I am trying to do this, but I don't have much luck.